# Does Spring BindingResult or FormError clear a field that has an error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have checked both the [BindingResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) and [FieldError](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html) Javadocs (and source) and can't find a definite answer to this question.   When the following code is executed in a Spring MVC Controller method (on a POST), the field that fails validation is displayed as blank when the form is redisplayed.   Is this behavior intended?   Can I depend on it in all cases (fields that fail validation are returned as blank?)

```
    //  Does the user's email address already exist?
    if (theUser != null) {
        result.addError(new FieldError("theForm", "emailAddress", null, false, new String[] { "theAccount.emailAddress.alreadyInUse" }, null, null));
        return ".createAccount";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check again `FieldError` constructor, according to JavaDocs, 3rd parameter is rejected field value:

```
rejectedValue - the rejected field value
```

The exact part of code which overrides value is in `AbstractBindingResult` class:

```
public Object getFieldValue(String field) {
    FieldError fieldError = getFieldError(field);
    // Use rejected value in case of error, current bean property value else.
    Object value = (fieldError != null ? fieldError.getRejectedValue() :
            getActualFieldValue(fixedField(field)));
    // Apply formatting, but not on binding failures like type mismatches.
    if (fieldError == null || !fieldError.isBindingFailure()) {
        value = formatFieldValue(field, value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

So while you provide `FieldError` class with null `rejectedValue`, the form field is cleared. As or me, I've always used `rejectValue` instead of `addError`:

```
result.rejectValue( "field", "errorCode" );
```

Comment: D'Oh!   Stupidness on my part.   Thanks for pointing that out.